# git log --oneline doesn't work, displays nothing

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In vscode, I have a repo with two commits, ie. `"first commit"` and `"second commit"`. I'm using git through the vscode powershell terminal.

`git log` works well, it returns

```
commit ffd6d05ac4b94fa5a85c9ca43798e436df8b3097
Author: myname <myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 27 11:26:32 2021 -0300

    second commit

commit 18f1b79f445f05db4b538800c174c1640a17f55d
Author: myname <myemail>
Date:   Sat Mar 27 10:32:24 2021 -0300

    first commit

~
(END)
```

but when I enter `git log --oneline` it returns empty

I also tried `git log --pretty=oneline` which also returns nothing

[image: screenshot after git log --oneline]

git version is    `git version 2.23.0.windows.1`

vscode version is `1.53.2`

Comment: Out of curiosity! what is output for git log --pretty=oneline

Comment: @Sharad It's returns nothing too

Comment: What if you did it via a terminal/prompt instead of VS code?

Comment: @astrochun in a terminal outside vscode, in the same directory is worse, even `git log` which used to work doesn't display anything.

Comment: That would suggest that there's not .git folder in that working directory.

Comment: @astrochun ther is a `.git` folder. And in vscode terminal, `git log` shows all the commits properly. I can even `checkout` any of them. It only has problem with `--oneline` in the terminal

Comment: Can you just provide the `git log` in the your question? The fact that a regular terminal command of `git log` or `git status` is "worse" suggests something is wrong. You really have told us much of how you set up this project through VS code.

Comment: @astrochun I've now added the `git log` result

Comment: What terminal/shell are you running this in (e.g. Powershell 7 in Windows Terminal)? When you say 'returns nothing' is it returning invisible lines (i.e. foreground and background colours are the same)? Have you tried a new git repo to test it on (preferably using just command lines without VS Code)?

Comment: Have you checked other `.git` repository? This could help identify whether the issue is VS Code, `git`, or the repository itself.

Comment: @PiersMyers direclty with the terminal, when I enter `git log`, it displays some text and disappears immediately.

Comment: Can you supply a screen shot of your terminal after you have typed `git log --oneline`

Comment: @PiersMyers I've added that now.

Comment: is the output of `git log` shown in the question also from a vscode terminal? It would be helpful to ignore vscode (unless that's actually relevant? seems unlikely unless the same commands act differently when ran via vscode terminal and another terminal) and just show the commands and output using a powershell/terminal window. It's quite odd for `git log` to show there is history and `git log --oneline` to show nothing. Also whilst I know some comments effectively asked for it - please don't add images of text, just put the text :).

Comment: @AD7six yes the output was from the vscode terminal. in direct powershell/cmd `git log` displays something and disappears immediately, for at most 100ms maybe, and nothing. at least it maintains its display in the vscode terminal. I am also suspecting it maybe due to the fact that `git log` is trying to display it in `vi` just like in Linux, and the incompatibility caused this (the disappearing immediately in direct terminal). I am saying this because it is a it you have pressed down <kbd>q</kbd> and entered the command, quitting it immediately.

Comment: In vscode terminal, I have also tried to change the default terminal app, cmd/powershell, in case it solved it, but no change.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that `git log --oneline` can return an empty result. One has to conclude that the output is being piped somewhere else.

Comment: As @matt said, if `git log` shows two commits, `git log --oneline` will also show two commits. The difference *must* be that the output is being captured and not shown somehow. It's not at all clear to me how that could be, though. The talk about seeing output that disappears quickly suggests that it's being put up in a separate region that gets erased afterwards, and perhaps with the oneline output it's fast enough that it does not even flicker.

Comment: Try doing a `git log > test.log`. This will capture it  in the test.log before it disappear, hopefully. How did you install `git`? You might consider getting `git-bash` installed and trying it through there.

Comment: `git log --oneline >> d:\test.txt` worked well. Thank you, everyone. after repetitive reinstalling, I finally found out that the git still in use was the one installed in anaconda environment, I finally removed it through `conda remove git` and installed a new one from git-scm.com. it now works well.

Comment: `maybe due to the fact that git log is trying to display it in vi just like in Linux` - `git log` does _not_ use vi to display any output on linux, it just outputs to stdout - like any other command. From the 100ms comment I suspect a funky pager setup maybe? `echo $PAGER; PAGER= git log` (or windows equivalent) would clarify/eliminate that. If you found the reason please edit the question to focus on the problem, write a detailed answer, and accept it to close the question.

Comment: `git --no-pager log`

Comment: I had thought this might be a `vim` issue. I never used `conda`'s `git`. Have a different version locally and never had a problem with `conda` environment.

Comment: @AD7six I'vent found the real reason except the fact that it was because of condas's git. I am now unable to reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

incase it helps someone else, the reason is that the git being used was one I had installed with Anaconda package. I don't know why it was behaving this way.

I uninstalled it with `conda remove` and then installed git for windows from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/download). And it now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current git which seems to be broken and re-install the latest git for Windows from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/download/win) or [gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/)